# ANSYS Design Modeller more significant figures

Tags: design, ansys, computer-aided-design, ansys-workbench

I need to just get the volume from ANSYS Design Modeller but I would like a higher number of significant figures rather than just 5 (See picture).
How do I do this?
Thank you for your help!

[image: ANSYS screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Since I have not comment rights, I'm gonna write this non-answer here (if someone with power reads this, please make this a comment). I believe all ANSYS licences should have access to **SpaceClaim** (the other/newer CAD editor in the package), measuring the volume of a solid is straightforward from the ***Measure*** panel, which has the option to adjust the number of significant figures. I do not know how to do it from Design Modeller.

Comment: Thank you, yes I've set it now! Im sorry my questions are so terrible... I have started ti try use ANSYS spaceclaim instead. When I create cylinders, how do I find the details of how long it is. I can only find out the radius in the box?

Comment: @657933 If you are creating new cylinders, you'll be asked to define the diameter and height, you can later modify these dimensions using the **Pull** button in the **Design tab**.
If you are importing those cylinders and the round part of your cylinder is a "circular entity" (as opposed to splines or anything else), you can use the **Measure** panel to measure both the diameter and the height. To measure the radius you'll need to click on edge of the circle side, which will give you the diameter and perimeter, and for the height you will need to select both flat surfaces (using the _Ctrl_ key

Comment: This is enough to be an answer imho